# Difference between "off", "down", "up" and "along"

Tags: prepositions

Consider:

> I live off Downing Street.
>
> I live down Downing Street.
>
> I live along Downing Street.
>
> I live up Downing Street.

Are these sentences all acceptable? If so, do they mean exactly the same thing? That is, you walk along the street and you'll find my house on either side of the street.

Comment: Broadly, they all mean that you live at the place that links to Downing St.

Comment: So what kind of link will it be? several blocks away or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they all mean roughly the same thing – if you told me one of these statements, I'd expect your address to be something like 1427 Downing Street (or someplace near that) – but there might be some **contextual** differences in when you would say them.

First off, I don't think any of the four would be my choice of preposition if someone asked me where I live. Instead, I'd usually say:

> I live **on** Downing Street.

or, if I was giving the exact address:

> I live **at** 1427 Downing Street.

However, some of the prepositions you mention are often given **when people provide directions**. Consider the map below:

[image: map]

Let's also assume Pace St. is a fairly well-known location – if you and I were in a conversation, we'd both probably know where that road is, and how to get to it. With that in mind, here are some questions you might ask, and how I might answer them:

> *Where do your kids go to school?*
> At the Goddard School.
> *Oh, where's that?*
> **The Goddard School is *off of* Pace Street.**

Actually, the school is **on** Olympia Ave, but I'm guessing that, if you knew where Olympia Avenue was, you wouldn't have asked me where the school is. So I use ***off*** to tell you a major road that the school is near.

> *Where is your Graphics shop?*
> It's on Santa Fe Drive.
> *Hmm, I don't know where that is.*
> **Santa Fe Drive runs *along* the river.**

Directionally, *along* usually means *roughly parallel with*. (I could have also said, "The river runs along Santa Fe Drive.")

Now, let's pretend I live where the orange square is, and my friend Monica lives where the blue square is.

> *Where do you live?*
> I live on Calais Drive.
> *Isn't that close to where Monica lives?*
> **Yes, Monica lives just *up* the road from me.**

When giving directions, *up* and *down* might be roughly synonymous, and they don't necessarily connote hills. I could have just as easily said *down* instead of *up*. In fact, one could even argue that *up* means "further down the road," and *down* means "further up the road."

These adjectives are flexible, and can be used in ways other than those I've described here. But I've tried to at least point out some of the subtle differences. I would not say that the school is *along* Pace Street, but I might say it's *down* Olympia Avenue.

Comment: The map was a random map I picked off of Google maps. It's a neighborhood near Denver, CO. I added the red circles and colored squares.

Answer (score 0):

They mean that your home is linked to Downing Street one or the other way.

> - *I live off Downing Street* - Your home is on the road that's a bit away from Downing Street (I think it's also used when your house is on the road that is parallel to Downing Street).
> - *I live down Downing Street* - Your home is at some lower position of Downing Street.
> - *I live along Downing Street* - Your home is on a line or course parallel and close to Downing Street.
> - *I live up Downing Street* - opposite to *down* i.e. Your home is at some upper position of Downing Street.

**Please note:** Each of those preposition words mean several things. For instance, in *walking down the street*, the *down* refers to in a descending direction along, upon, into, or through the street.

Comment: Do you mean my house couldn't stand on either side of Downing Street, and I couldn't walk along it and find my house; rather, I still need to get away from Downing Street to find my house, right? Is this the same for all of these examples above?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng in each sentence, the position of your house is changed. Of course, the house will be on the side of the street, won't it be? You will certainly find your house on either side (because we are not concerned about the this/that side of the road). Yes, in case if your house is *off* the road, you'll have to find it a bit as it means away from the road.

Comment: Perhaps I put it in a wrong way. Is it that the position of my house is not on Downing Street for each of these sentences?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Yes, for that *off Downing Street* it is not. Rest of those indicate that your house **is** on the street.

Comment: OK, suppose I living on a street vertical to Downing Street, Is it OK to say that I live off Downing Street?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng you got it!