# "waste" versus "waste up"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there a difference in meaning between "waste" versus "waste up"? I was not able to find the exact meaning of "waste up" online. It's a phrase from a movie called "Everything Everywhere All at Once".

> You guys are wasting a trip up. Copy?

Comment: It does not say 'waste up', it says 'trip up'. Possibly as in "You are wasting a trip up [to my city]". Otherwise you would not split **waste** and **up**, as in the dubious "You are wasting up a trip." People throw in unnecesssary prepositions everywhere though, such as in "listen up" where "listen" is clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### "Waste up" is not a phrase. The "up" belongs to "trip."

You are parsing the phrase as "waste [something] up," similar to "use [something] up." But that's not the case; "waste up" is not idiomatic in English.

Instead, the thing they are wasting is "a trip up." Here "up" can mean literally higher in elevation, to the north, away from the center of a city, or many other things depending on the context. See [Usage of "up" vs. "down"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41259/usage-of-up-vs-down?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I don't know why I got a -1 as I really didn't understand the meaning. thus the question. Thank you all for your assistance and help!