# Does the "up" in my example mean "along"?

Tags: prepositions

My own example:

> There are several beauty parlors **up the street**.

Does "up" in that context mean the same as "along"?

Comment: Not exactly, but very close. I hope someone will explain more in a good answer.

Comment: I think it means along the street that is away from you.

Comment: Related: [Walking up/down the street](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/399/walking-up-down-a-level-road-street); [Why do you go down the street](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49615/why-do-you-always-go-down-the-street); [Difference between, up, down, off, and along](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19178/difference-between-off-down-up-and-along).

Answer (score 1):

In this context the preposition "*up*" usually means ***direction***.  Which direction exactly is meant by "*up*" can differ depending on locality, city planning, traditions, landscape and other factors.

Some choices (this is not an exhaustive list by any means) are:
 - in the direction of *increasing altitude* (toward the top of a hill,
   for instance)
 - in the direction of *increasing house numbers*
 - in the direction *away from the center* of the town/city (see also "*uptown*")

It is quite possible that the speaker simply meant "further in the street".

Similar phrase: "***down the street***".