# On the road vs beside the road vs down the road

Tags: prepositions

Can you tell me the difference among the following sentences?

My house is on the road

My house is down the road.

My house is beside/by the road.

My house is along the road.

My house is up the road.

Comment: _Down the road/up the road/along the road_ all mean that the house is some distance away along the road we are on or near. (Down and up may, or may not, imply a difference of altitude.)  _Beside/by the road_ means what it says. "My house is on the road" sounds a bit odd, as though the house is actually standing in the middle of the road, but we can say that a building is on a named street.

Comment: I believe the below link will help you : https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19178/136425

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in how you use them.

Different prepositions work better with different contexts and constructions, as in:

My house is on the road to the dam. (Take the road to the dam and you will see my house.)

My house is up/down the road from library. (It's further on from the library, and may be up or down an incline.)

My house is beside the road to town. (It's very close to the road)

My house is along the road to town. (Unusual; carries the sense of on the road to town but **along** generally follows a verb, **to walk/run/drive along**. However, to say the house **is just along the road** means just a bit further.).

This question is less about the meaning and more about the choice of preposition for each context. Some fit better than others.